# Align input text fields in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have multiple text input fields that I would like to display in 2 columns. My basic example uses, `splitLayout` to do this.

[image]

The names of each text input field (ie, AAA, BBBBBBB...) are fixed and known in advance. I would like:

- The text input fields themselves to align
- The second column of text input fields to be closer to the first column
- More space between the first and second row

Something close to:
[image]

How can that be done in R Shiny?

Basic Example

```
# Form fields displayed in two columns with Shiny

library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

ui <- fluidRow(
  box(width = 12, title = "Here is a Title", 
      splitLayout(
        textInput("a", "AAA"),
        textInput("b", "BBBBBBB")
      ),
      splitLayout(
        textInput("c", "CCCCCCCCC"),
        textInput("d", "SSSSSSSSS")
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tags$table`.

```R
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

ui <- fluidRow(
  box(width = 12, title = "Here is a Title",
    tags$table(
      tags$tr(
        tags$td("AAA"),
        tags$td(textInput("a", NULL)),
        tags$td("BBBBBBB"),
        tags$td(textInput("b", NULL))
      ),
      tags$tr(
        tags$td("CCCCCCCCC"),
        tags$td(textInput("c", NULL)),
        tags$td("SSSSSSSSS"),
        tags$td(textInput("d", NULL))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```